# Centering <td>'s in a <div>

Tags: html, css, menu, navbar, nav

I am fixing up a website for a tech night at my school. The navbar was on the side which isn't my favorite view for the bar so I put it on top, but I can't get the table data or menu to center in the div.

http://jsfiddle.net/ksta1584/c88qswsx/

`<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/ksta1584/c88qswsx/">Link<a/>`

I would also like instead of the lines disappearing when you scroll over that they are all in equally sized boxes and the boxes sort of "pop" out. I'm not sure how to do that and can't get the border to appear.

Comment: `<td>` must be contained inside `<tr>` you have no row element `<tr>` on your fiddle example, and `<th>` doesn't go inside `<td>` either, valid mark up is key to style things properly.

Comment: Please include the *minimal, relevant code in the question itself* if you are looking to get debugging help. jsfiddles break

Comment: Thanks @gillesc as I said, I was redoing it from someone else's work, I didn't even think about looking for code errors.

Comment: @Zach Saucier it told me I couldn't post a jsfiddle unless there was code so I just coded in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in your .nav:

```
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center; 
    position:relative;
    top:35%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `margin:0 auto` into your `.nav` rule